# Stopping a systemd *user* unit when a USB device is removed

Tags: systemd

[systemd doesn't stop the service when the device is removed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/528803/systemd-doesnt-stop-the-service-when-the-device-is-removed) suggests adding a remove rule to udev which simply runs `systemd --no-block stop SOMETHING.service`

But what if the unit in question is a *user* unit, started with `ENV{SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS}`? `systemd --user --no-block stop SOMETHING.service` will fail, I assume because udev runs it as not the user for which the unit should be stopped.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to not try running systemd commands from udev, but instead use `StopWhenUnneeded=true`. This does however require fixing [an underlying issue with the device unit](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/7587) which I've detailed in [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/593033/33203).